# Nixos how can I search for packages in a specific channel?

Tags: nixos, nix

`nix-env -v -qaP '*'` currently returns all the packages available from all my channels.

How can I specify to return packages from a specific channel for example `unstable` / `18.03`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
nix-env -f "https://github.com/NixOS/nixpkgs-channels/archive/775fb69ed73e7cf6b7d3dd9853a60f40e8efc340.tar.gz" -qa '*'
```

I grabbed the commit from selecting the branch on github: https://github.com/NixOS/nixpkgs/tree/nixos-19.03